# compare structure and key names of two dictionaries, not values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I have two dictionaries like this:

```
dict_1 = {
    "key_1": {
        "key_1_1": "test",
        "key_1_2": "test",
        "key_1_3": "test",
        "key_1_4": [
            {
                "key": "test",
                "value": "test_value"
            },
            {
                "key": "test",
                "value": "test_value"
            }
        ]
    }
}

dict_2 = {
    "key_1": {
        "key_1_1": "test1",
        "key_1_2": "test1",
        "key_1_3": "test1",
        "key_1_4": [
            {
                "key": "test1",
                "value": "test_value1"
            },
            {
                "key": "test1",
                "value": "test_value1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can compare these two dictionaries and return either True or False.
I have tried:

```
dict_1 == dict2
```

and also deepdiff but it is returning differences in values. In my case, dictionary structure are the same, also key names are the same and it should return me True. I don't care about the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that replaces all scalar values in your object with a dummy value, such as None.

```
dict_1 = {
    "key_1": {
        "key_1_1": "test",
        "key_1_2": "test",
        "key_1_3": "test",
        "key_1_4": [
            {
                "key": "test",
                "value": "test_value"
            },
            {
                "key": "test",
                "value": "test_value"
            }
        ]
    }
}

dict_2 = {
    "key_1": {
        "key_1_1": "test1",
        "key_1_2": "test1",
        "key_1_3": "test1",
        "key_1_4": [
            {
                "key": "test1",
                "value": "test_value1"
            },
            {
                "key": "test1",
                "value": "test_value1"
            }
        ]
    }
}

def just_keys(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k: just_keys(v) for k,v in obj.items()}
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [just_keys(item) for item in obj]
    else:
        return None

def keys_equal(a,b):
    return just_keys(a) == just_keys(b)


print(just_keys(dict_1))
print(just_keys(dict_2))
print(keys_equal(dict_1, dict_2))
```

Result:

```
{'key_1': {'key_1_1': None, 'key_1_2': None, 'key_1_3': None, 'key_1_4': [{'key': None, 'value': None}, {'key': None, 'value': None}]}}
{'key_1': {'key_1_1': None, 'key_1_2': None, 'key_1_3': None, 'key_1_4': [{'key': None, 'value': None}, {'key': None, 'value': None}]}}
True
```